# += operator overloading in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class Fracpri
attr_accessor:whole, :numer, :denom, :dec, :flofrac
def initialize()
    puts "Hey! It's an empty constructor"
end
def getFraction(whole,numer,denom)
    @whole=whole
    @numer=numer
    @denom=denom
end
def showFraction
    puts "#{whole} #{numer}/#{denom}"
end
def +=(obj)
    if(self.whole+(self.numer.to_f/self.denom.to_f) < obj.whole+(obj.numer.to_f/obj.denom.to_f))
        puts "Yes"
    else
        puts "No"
    end
end

end
puts "10 question"
r3=Fracpri.new()
r3.getFraction(1,2,3)
r2=Fracpri.new()
r2.getFraction(4,6,5)
r1=Fracpri.new()
r1.getFraction(2,6,5)
r1 += r2
```

this is the error message I'm getting:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' or '\n'

    def +=(obj)
          ^

 syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

suggest me how to rectify this error so that i can perform overloading,i need to add a constant using "+=" operator

Comment: I thought `+=` was something from C, C++, perl etc

Comment: Practice correct code indentation. Your editor can help you, and your future self and anyone you're working with will thank you, and your employer won't point out the need in a code-review.

Comment: @theTinMan , the code is indented

Comment: `+=` is a form of [Abbreviated Assignment](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment). If `op` is the operator `+` , `-`,  `*`, `/`, `%`, `**`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `<<` or `>>`, Ruby expands `a op= b` to `a = a op b` before evaluating the expression. Here `op` is `+`, so `a += b` expands to `a = a + b`....

Comment: ...The operators `||` and `&&` are treated somewhat  are differently. `a ||= b` sets `a` equals to `b` if `a` is `nil`, `false` or `undefined`, whereas `a &&= b` sets `a` to `b` if `a` is neither `nil`, `false` nor undefined, and if `a` is undefined it is set equal to `nil`. There can be no space between `op` and `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to override `=`, nor variants such as `+=`. These are built in keywords and not *methods* such as `+`.

If you change your patch from `def +=(obj)` to `def +(obj)`, you can still call `r1 += r2` and it will have the same effect as if you'd patched `+=`. This is because `+=` is calling your patched `+` method under the hood.

By the way, your `+` method doesn't actually return a value so any time you call `+=` it will always result in nil .... but it seems like this is still a WIP so hopefully you can sort that bit out.